# Create custom UIButton with multiple images and shift Label and maybe add properties

Tags: ios, uibutton

for an iPad application in ios5.0 and arc, I need to create a button that has an image covering the entire button, and needs to have another transparent image at the bottom half of this button image OR have the button text label covering the bottom half of this button image.

1. In posts on this site I've read that using button subclass to just change the appearance of the UiButton should not be done. However, if I don't subclass, can I add these transparent image/and shift the button label? if so, how?
2. In case I need to add properties to the button, what is the best way to go about it.
3. If subclassing is the only option, can you also pls give pointers on what are the methods that i must absolutely override and any other such memory/performance considerations that I must keep in mind

Pointers to Any tutorials or third party libraries would be most appreciated.. Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree on "subclassing UIButton is not good". That's exactly why inheritance and subclassing mechanisms exist. In all platforms, the framework provides a base foundation for general needs, and you do extend them in the case standard stuff does not satisfy your needs. And you do it by subclassing.

As long as you know what you do, and what you do works for you and solves your problem, you're fine.

When you subclass `UIButton`, depending on what you actually want to achieve, you may want to override `init:`, `initWithRect:`, `layoutSubviews:`, `awakeFromNib:` methods.

Inspecting some subclasses would also help:

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSCheckBoxView

https://github.com/ardalahmet/CopyableCell

For `UIButton`, you can inspect [this](http://www.binpress.com/app/glossy-button-for-ios/968) component. Source code may help a lot.